# How to use visual studio 19 to debug a php app running on an azure Ubuntu VM

Tags: php, visual-studio, azure, virtual-machine, xdebug

I’ve configured the virtual machine, installed apache2, php, MySQL and xdebug. The website works and I’ve configured VS but nothing happens when I debug the project in VS.
Note I have to use a VM because there is some trickery that is being done with open VPN.

I am no expert with PHP as I come from the ASP.NET world and I have never used Xdebug before.

I've been asked to add some additional information but the /etc/php/7.2/apache2/php.ini file is too large to add into this post.  If you want some more information please ask for a section and I will post it.

In the mods-available folder is an xdebug.ini file that contains:

```
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_handler = dbgp
xdebug.remote_host = 127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_log = /tmp/xdebug_remote.log
xdebug.remote_mode = req
xdebug.remote_port = 9000 #if you want to change the port you can change
```

I've also set up an inbound rule in Azure for the server to a allow port 9000.

When running VS I have set up the Server URL and specified Xdebug Port 9000.

DBGp proxy is not set.

Thank you

Tim

Comment: You're basically asking us to google this for you... In any case, you have added so little information (no config, not settings, nothing beyond "it doesn't" work) for us to do anything with.

Comment: I have googled many times and have not found what I am looking for. I am not asking you to google it for me I am asking has anyone done this before and if they have a procedure or some information. 
If this has never been done before then I will carry on my research and rest assured I will post my findings for the benefit of those who want to do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to get something to work.

I updated the xdebug.ini like this:

```
zend_extension=/usr/lib/php/20170718/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.remote_connect_back = 1
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_handler = dbgp
xdebug.remote_host = 86.180.220.70
xdebug.remote_log = /tmp/xdebug_remote.log
xdebug.remote_mode = req
xdebug.remote_port = 9000 #if you want to change the port you can change
xdebug.idekey = "php-vs"
```

And, crucially, opened the firewall on my machine for port 9000.

Now I can't seem to set any break points in php that actually hit.

I'm assuming this has something to do with path mapping - plenty of stuff on google for Code but little if nothing for Visual Studio...

I have to say the documentation for doing things like this is SHOCKINGLY bad.  Most examples are for a Windows php.ini file, not for Linux.  If your a seasoned php programmer your probably used to it but for a newbie like me its an absolute minefield.